# How to show all data in textbox from datagrid?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpfdatagrid

What would be the simplies way to show all data in text boxes from selected item... For example:
[image]

if I click on Web Site data, how to show all other data from the same Salon in text boxes?

This is how I show data in datagrid from MySql:

```
 private void btnShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string connection = "server=localhost;user id=root; password=root; database=pop-sf40-database";
        string query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM salons");

        MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connection);
        cn.Open();

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);

        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(data);
        dgSalons.DataContext = data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

```
// Assumes the DataGrid is bound to a DataTable.
DataTable myTable = (DataTable) dgSalons.DataSource;

txtSample.Text = myTable.Rows[dgSalons.CurrentCell.RowNumber].Cells["Yourcolname"].Value.ToString();
```